# Using pipes inside a class in C++

Tags: c++, file, class, pipe

I'm trying to use [this](http://sushpa.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/calling-gnuplot-from-within-c-or-python/) tutorial to make plots with Gnuplot in C++. However I will be using the pipe to Gnuplot from within a class, but then I run into some problems:

I've got a header file where I declare all variables etc. I need to declare the `pipe`-variable here too, but how do I do that?

I've tried doing it straight away, but it doesn't work:

#### Logger.h:

```
class Logger {
    FILE pipe;
}
```

#### Logger.cpp:

```
Logger::Logger() { //Constructor
    *pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
}
```

Gives the error `Logger.cpp:28: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘*((Logger*)this)->Logger::pipe = popen(((const char*)"gnuplot -persist"), ((const char*)"w"))’`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your FILE needs to be a pointer to FILE

`FILE *pipe;`

then

`pipe = popen(...)`

Comment: Tried with *pipe, but it gives the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Update: My bad. Works now. Thanks a lot! :)